# How to limit the rows and split the tables according to key and value? - PHP & JSON

Tags: php, json

I am trying to limit the table to 10 rows if more than 10 rows are found create a new table. The data is read from JSON. The code looks something like this:

```
<?php

$json = '{"test1": {
        "sub1": [
            "1", "2", "3"
        ],
        "sub2": [
            "1", "2", "3","4"
        ],
        "sub3": [
            "1", "2", "3","4"
        ],
        "sub4": [
            "1", "2"
        ]
    }
  }';

$results = json_decode($json);

echo '<table>';
foreach ($results->test1 as $key => $jsons) {

    foreach ($jsons as $value) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.ucwords($key).'</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';

    }
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

The required output looks something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Sub1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sub2</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sub3</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Sub3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sub4</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have used `foreach` loop do I have to use `for` loop to count the size of the JSON file and limit it to 10 and then continue?

Or is there a better approach?

Comment: Use incrementing variable inside foreach, once you achieve the count, break the loop

Comment: @Thamilan an example would be great!

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use a boolean header on the flags. Then to cut it use modulo `% 10 == 0`. Below is just create a new batch using that.

```
$results = json_decode($json);
$new_array = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($results->test1 as $k => $value) {
    $header = true;
    foreach($value as $k2 => $v) {
        if($i % 10 == 0 || $header) {
            $key_pair = array($k, $v);
        } else {
            $key_pair = array(null, $v);
        }
        $i++;
        $new_array[] = $key_pair;
        $header = false;
    }
}

foreach(array_chunk($new_array, 10) as $value) {
echo '<table>'; 
    foreach($value as $tr) {
        echo '<tr><td>', implode('</td><td>', $tr), '</td></tr>';
    }
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: So the `<table>` tag comes in the first loop?

Comment: @akshay just like the one you have, just before the loop

Comment: Oh. But that doesn't create a new table right? just one big table. Could please look at the desired output.

Comment: @akshay wait cut down it to 10 items inside?

Comment: Yes! Once the 10 items are done, a new table with the previous key if any.

Comment: @akshay you could use the `% 10` modulo to cut into a new table